# How to run/port MongoDB on iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mongodb

I wonder if it is possible to run MongoDB on iPad as it is or do I have to port it to iPhone OS?

Answer (score 3):

I honestly have no experience with iPhone/iPad development and imagine that there'll be some work involved to get it working; but MongoDB is capable of being run as an embedded database - maybe that would be the way to go. Check out the code for the MongoDB tools (tools/import.cpp, etc.) - those optionally run using the embedded client.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB runs in a separate process. Can iPad deal with two or more processes?

Comment: No, MongoDB cannot run multiple processes.

Comment: Doesn't matter that MongoDB uses only one process. You need one process on the iPad for the app and one process on the iPad for MongoDB if you run MongoDb non-embedded. So I don't understand Roman Kagan's reaction. I have to say that I didn't know that you can run MongoDB embedded. But I still don't understand Roman's reaction.